# Hitting times of Markov chain/process have always finite moments?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider an irreducible ergodic Markov chain on a finite state space $S$. Then any state is positive recurrent and this should suffice to conclude that the mean hitting time of state $s \in S$ is finite. Is this reasoning correct?

What can be said, in general, about the second (or higher) moment of such hitting time? Is it always finite? If not, which additional conditions guarantee that it is finite?

Are the answers still the same if we consider an irreducible ergodic Markov process (i.e. in continuous time), always on a finite state space?

Comment: On a finite state space, every hitting time $T$ has some exponential finite moment, that is, there exists $s\gt0$ such that $E[\exp(sT)]$ is finite. In particular, every moment $E[T^n]$ is finite.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this result? Does it apply both to discrete and continuous time?

Comment: Not at the moment. Yes. (See answer.)

Comment: Notice that a discrete-time Markov chain checks whether it hits $s$ or not at every tick. Thus roughly speaking, the chain performs a Bernoulli trial at each tick and we expect that $T$ has exponential tail. Of course this is not the exact picture if $|S| \geq 3$, but when $S$ is finite, we can still formalize this idea to show that $T$ indeed has exponential tail.

Comment: @SangchulLee This argument would be relevant if every hitting time had exactly exponential tail. Unfortunately, not all of them have.

Comment: @Did, Maybe my wording was inaccurate. I meant to refer to the exponential decay of the tail, which you showed in your answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> On a finite state space, every hitting time $T$ has some exponential finite moment, that is, there exists $a>0$ such that $E[\exp(aT)]$ is finite. In particular, every moment $E[T^n]$ is finite.

To show this in the discrete time case, first note that, for every state $x$, the hitting time $T$ of $s$ starting from $x$ is almost surely finite because $x$ and $s$ communicate and the state space is finite. Hence there exists some finite $n_x$ such that $P[T\gt n_x\mid X_0=x]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-1}$. Choose any finite $n$ such that $P[T\gt n\mid X_0=x]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-1}$ for every $x$, for example $n=\max\{n_x\mid x\ \text{state}\}$. Note that this maximum exists (and is finite), once again because the state space is finite. For every $k\geqslant0$,
$$
P[T\gt k+n]=\sum_xP[T\gt k+n,X_k=x,T\gt k],
$$
hence
$$
P[T\gt k+n]=\sum_xP[T\gt k+n\mid X_k=x,T\gt k]\cdot P[X_k=x,T\gt k].
$$
For every $x$, $P[T\gt k+n\mid X_k=x,T\gt k]=P[T\gt n\mid X_0=x]$ by the (simple) Markov property at time $k$, hence
$$
P[T\gt k+n]\leqslant\sum_x\mathrm e^{-1}\cdot P[X_k=x,T\gt k]=\mathrm e^{-1}\cdot P[T\gt k].
$$
Iterating this, one gets $P[T\gt in]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-i}$ for every $i$, hence $P[T\gt k]\leqslant\mathrm e^{1-(k/n)}$ for every $k$. In particular, $E[\mathrm e^{aT}]$ is finite for every positive $a\lt1/n$.

The continuous time finite state space case is similar.