# First Time Passage References

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, markov-chains

Does someone have any references for this topic regarding distribution for first time passage?

Details included in this topic.
[Hitting times of Markov chain/process have always finite moments?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351100/hitting-times-of-markov-chain-process-have-always-finite-moments/1503891?noredirect=1#comment3063564_1503891)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start, although not mathematically the most rigor, is in my opinion Redner's book "A guide to first-passage processes" by Sidney Redner
Cambridge University Press. There are many references there too.